# What is the difference between "path" and "passage"?

Tags: nouns

> Water is supplied to the tank through the **water supply passage/path**.

I would like to know "passage" or "path" which is better for the sentence above.

It seems to me that "passage" implies a physical object such as a pipe, whereas "path" implies an abstract object such as a drawn line.

Comment: Without consulting a dictionary for actual definitions, I think of a *path* as a *trail*, a worn route through a landscape or physical feature.  A path is often a natural occurring feature created by the passage of travelers.  I think of a *passage* as a *passageway*, a manmade portal allowing entry into a physical space.  I don't think either of your supplied options works.

Comment: They are both bad. Water is supplied to a tank through a hose, through a pipe. For example.

Comment: What about a "channel"?

Answer (score 2):

A [path](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/path) is just a route between two places. A [passage](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/passage) is usually long, narrow, and partially or fully enclosed, for example between two buildings: when used about water, it is usually a channel that boats can pass along.

A native English speaker would use the appropriate word to describe the structure of the route. Here are a few examples: you can find many more by looking for [synonyms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/channel).

- [pipe](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pipe) - a tube, normally manufactured somewhere other than where it is installed
- [culvert](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/culvert) - man-made, covered
- [channel](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/channel) - open, natural or man-made
- [aqueduct](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aqueduct) - elevated, open, man made